Facet for Convex hull
Recently I went through an article where they mentioned that in order to be an inequality as a facet of a convex hull, it must be (a) not an improper face (b) it is the only inequality satisfied with equality by all points of the convex hull along with a linear combination of other equality constraints.
Could someone please explain with a simple example? Is it true for all cases? Also, is there any reference that has a good explanations on this topic? As far I knew, facets were identified based on linear independent points or dimension of the convex hull -1. But this seems a different condition.
